# Collaboratively working with a WebDesigner - Best practices

Tags: web-development, agile, web-applications, java-ee

I'm a programmer. I have always worked by myself.
I usually do only back-end, but now I have a webproject that I want to hand the "View" part to a designer to make
it beautiful.

What I'm looking for are suggestions, best practices, recommended literature to make it easy and separate (easy to merge) for both parts.

I googled a lot, so what I want is your personal opinion, experience on this subject.

1 - The back-end will be Java.
2 - Besides the back-end I haven't chosen (opinions ???) on what is best (JSF, only HTML (REST)) for the frontend

Any help and insight is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of framework is less important than actually following MVC good design principles and keeping controller logic out of the view, but even this will be difficult to do with many frameworks becoming more and more tied to componentized Javascript libraries.

For example, in a typical JSF page, you might see the following markup:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{controller.beanList}" var="bean">
  <h:outputText value="#{bean.description}" rendered="#{(bean.id % 2) eq 0}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Clearly the repeat element is not a style element, but a component that creates a form elements of its children repeated for each element in the value list.  You also see how only output text will be rendered on the page for beans with an even id.  This can be significant business logic within the EL expression that is not properly unit tested within your view, and thus something to look out for.  A web designer will not know what to do with this rendered attribute nor would you want the designer to specify such logic without it being covered by a unit test which you control.

Some web designers play a smaller role, and focus more on site templates, style sheets and images, while it is the responsibility of the front end developer to utilize these resources.  Sometimes they have to work closely with a developer when perhaps styling the page requires reorganization of form elements in such a way that it might affect controller logic or other presentation logic.

TL;DR It depends.

Comment: @marcelocbf Your welcome, I hope this helps.